# C++ macro token pasting with a trailing underscore

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to write a macro that automatically creates accessor and mutator methods which set a dirty flag.

```cpp
#define DIRTY_PROPERTY(type, name, var) \
private:                                \
    type ##var_;                        \
                                        \
public:                                 \
    type get##name() { return ##var_; } \
    void set##name(type val) {          \
        dirty_ = true;                  \
        ##var_ = val;                   \
    }
```

To be used like so:

```cpp
class RenderObject
{
    DIRTY_PROPERTY(bool, FlipX, flipX)
}
```

The issue I'm having is that it is gobbling up the trailing underscores in `##var_` and not replacing `##var` with the value of `var`.

How do I tell it that the leading `_` is not part of the variable name?

Comment: Are you looking for `var##_`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat :facepalm: yes I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `##` goes between the two tokens you're pasting together.  In this case, you're pasting `var` and `_` together, so `##var_` should be `var##_`.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a9a35f0fb6a1821)